# How do I pass multiple columns into a formula in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm creating a new spreadsheet for daytrading, where I want to automate the calculations for every row. I have already looked at Google's custom function guide which deals with only one column. I have multiple columns whose values need to be taken into account. For example, I want:

> Column D1:D = (Column A1:A x Column B:B) - (Column C1:C)

How do I do this using custom functions only since they are cleaner and more easier to read (I have gotten this to work without using a custom formula and the solution is not readable, maintainable, or elegant)?

Edit: I'm familiar with this recursive formula from Google's guide on custom formulas but I don't know how to modify it for multiple columns:

```
function DOUBLE(input) {  
  if(input.map) {
    return input.map(DOUBLE);
  } else {
    return input * 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how do you expect a custom function to be cleaner than just =ARRAYFORMULA(A:A*B:B-C:C) ?  But if you insist on writing JavaScript, you should share what you already tried and did not work for you.

Comment: @ttarchala, I just updated my post to show what I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write custom functions that take arrays as parameters. Here is an example of a function that should multiply 2 columns and then subtract a third, as in your example (I haven't tested it, and it assumes that all arrays are the same size without error checking but this is just for you to get the idea):

```
function multAndSub(ary1, ary2, ary3) {

  var resultAry = [];

  for (var row=0; row<ary1.length; row++)
      resultAry.push(ary1[row]*ary2[row]-ary3[row]);

  return resultAry;
}
```

After you write the function, you can call it as any other formula from the spreadsheet:

```
=multAndSub(A:A, B:B, C:C)
```